# Nexus 7 XFCE install error

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

So I attempted to install package xubuntu-desktop on my Nexus 7,but it keeps getting this error:

```
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/x/xubuntu-meta/xubuntu-desktop_2.163_armhf.deb 404 Not Found
```

Is this something that can be fixed, or is XFCE simply not compatible with the Nexus 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That package has been upgraded, a simple `sudo apt-get update`